# How to run PHP script in the back by a jquery button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to run some PHP code from a file when I click a button from jQuery. This is the code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#btnSubmit").button().click(function(){
        alert("button 1");

        $.ajax({
        url: 'releaseBackEnd.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: {},
        dataType: 'xml',
        error: function(){
            alert('Error');
        },
        success: function(data){        
            //check error
            alert("success!");

        }
    });

    });
 });
```

It shows the alert of "error". I have the releaseBackEnd.php file in the same directory of the javascript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$("#btnSubmit").button().click(
```

to

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(
```

and check whether the php page is sending the response or not.

Try getting the error in the error callback function using the XMLHttpRequest.

```
error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

check the response in firebug console .. if u don't have firebug add it to your firefox using this link

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code...**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#btnSubmit").bind('click',function() {
        alert("button 1");

        $.ajax({
        url: 'releaseBackEnd.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: {},
        dataType: 'xml',
        error: function(){
            alert('Error');
        },
        success: function(data){        
            //check error
            alert("success!");

        }
    });

    });
 });
```

Comment: async: true,
data: {}, //pass appropriate data